How to use engine-mode with Google "site:"?
I use engine-mode for keyword searches. for example, with
  (use-package engine-mode
    :config 
    (engine-mode t)
    :bind
    (:map org-mode-map ("C-k" . nil))
    :bind-keymap
    ("C-k" . engine-mode-prefixed-map)
    )

and
(defengine Wikpedia-EN
  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s"
  :keybinding "w i e")

I can open the GNU Emacs Wikipedia in English page on a browser by typing C-k wie gnu emacs, which is very useful for plenty of websites.
However, for some websites, keyword search is not possible.
For these websites I thought of using google "site:" but I can't find out how to configure engine-mode for that.
Here is a concrete example:
There is no keyword search available for https://fragrantica.com/.
But I could show a page with the fragrantica page for Polo Sport as first result if I put polo sport site:https://fragrantica.com/ as a Google search query.
How could I use engine-mode to open a page with these Google results by typing C-k fra polo sport in Emacs?

Here is the solution:
(defengine fragrantica
  "https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://fragrantica.com %s"
:keybinding "f r a")

